# expecting 2 arguments got 1

Tags: python, list

new to programming with python, I'm trying to work with lists and I have a line that reads `holos.insert("holo_enter_info\n")` but for some reason it says it was expecting 2 arguments but it only got 1. I don't know what that means can anyone help me?

Comment: `list.insert()` needs two arguments: the position and the value to insert at that position.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `append()`, which adds to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

from [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert):

**insert() Parameters**

The `insert()` method takes two parameters:

- **index** - the index where the element needs to be inserted
- **element** - this is the element to be inserted in the list

> Notes:
>
> - If `index` is 0, the element is inserted at the beginning of the list.
> - If `index` is 3, the element is inserted after the 3rd element. Its position will be 4th.